# How to use Shaka packager with python sub-process call? I am getting this error Invalid stream descriptors name/value pairs:

Tags: python-3.x, video, subprocess, video-streaming, shaka

I am a newbie trying to use Shaka packager for a new app I am working on, I can't make it to work, it's throwing out this error `Invalid stream descriptors name/value pairs:` which I am not able to understand. Can anyone help with this piece of code, I don't understand where the error is coming from.

This is the code.

```
subprocess.call([
                settings.PACKAGER_PATH, "in={480p_path}, stream=audio, output=audio.mp4",
                "in={480p_path}, stream=video, output={480p_path}",
                 "in={1080p_path}, stream=video, output={1080p_path}", "--mpd_output {dash_path}"])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails parsing the arguments because a stream descriptor should be a single argument string containing key-value pairs separated by commas.

DASH example:

```
$ packager \
  in=h264_baseline_360p_600.mp4,stream=audio,output=audio.mp4 \
  in=input_text.vtt,stream=text,output=output_text.vtt \
  in=h264_baseline_360p_600.mp4,stream=video,output=h264_360p.mp4 \
  in=h264_main_480p_1000.mp4,stream=video,output=h264_480p.mp4 \
  in=h264_main_720p_3000.mp4,stream=video,output=h264_720p.mp4 \
  in=h264_high_1080p_6000.mp4,stream=video,output=h264_1080p.mp4 \
  --mpd_output h264.mpd
```

So you need to do:

```
subprocess.call([settings.PACKAGER_PATH, 
    "in={480p_path},stream=audio,output=audio.mp4",
    "in={480p_path},stream=video,output={480p_path}",
    [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, now I am getting this error `unknown command line flag 'mpd_output {dash_path}'`. Can you help me how to properly specify the output file?

Comment: @prehistoricbeast Check the example, you need to put two separate arguments in the array. Space is the delimiter.

Comment: I am sorry, I might sound dumb, but I am not able to understand what you meant with 2 separate arguments in the array. can you please explain a bit more? Thanks

Comment: @prehistoricbeast `[ ... "--mpd_output",  "{dash_path}"]`

Comment: Also, don't put spaces after the `,` for the previous stream descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this approach where `drm_command` is a single line command generate and or changed by python with variables. It's just a string without `\` and `\n' characters. This works perfectly well.

```
drm_command = 'sudo packager {var1}....'

drm_processor_response = Popen(f"({drm_command})", stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
output, errors = drm_processor_response.communicate()
log_update([drm_processor_response.returncode, errors.decode("utf-8"), output.decode("utf-8")])
```